# Multiple functions and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

This is a school assignment, so I don't expect too much help.  Unfortunately, the class is online and the teacher cannot lecture like one can in person, so it is difficult for me to understand certain concepts.  In this case it is the use of pointers and multiple functions.  My code compiles alright, but after inputting the information into the program, it crashes.  I feel lost, hopefully someone can help me understand this better as I really do want to improve my coding.  So I apologize if my code is horrendous:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int get_data(int *cust_num, int *kwh);
int calculate_charge(int *kwh, double *rate);                       
int print_results(int *cust_num, int *kwh, double *rate);                           

int
main(){

int pwr, tot_cust, tot_kwh, customer;
char ans;
double charge, tot_charge;

do{

/*get data*/
get_data(&customer, &pwr);


/*calculate data*/
calculate_charge(&pwr, &charge);


/*print data*/
print_results(&customer, &pwr, &charge);

/*continue?*/   
printf("\nDo you have any more data to input? (y/n)> ");
scanf("%c", ans);
tot_cust ++;
tot_kwh = tot_kwh + pwr;
tot_charge = tot_charge + charge;
}while(ans == 'y');
/*print final*/
printf("\nTotal Customers: %d  Total KWH used: %d  Total Charges:  
%.2f",  tot_cust, tot_kwh, tot_charge);

return 0;
}

 int get_data(int *cust_num, int *kwh){
*cust_num = *cust_num;
*kwh = *kwh;

printf("Please enter the customer number and the kwh> ");
scanf("%d", &cust_num);
scanf("%d", &kwh);



}

int calculate_charge(int *kwh, double *rate){

/*calculate cost*/
if(*kwh <= 300){
    *rate = .09 * *kwh;
}

else if ((*kwh > 300) && (*kwh <= 600)){
    *rate = .09 * 300 + ((*kwh - 300) * .08);
}

else if ((*kwh > 600) && (*kwh <= 1000)){
    *rate = .09 * 300 + .08 * 300 + ((*kwh - 600) * .06);
}
else {
    *rate = .09 * 300 + .08 * 300 + .06 * 400 + ((*kwh - 1000) * .05);
}

}

int print_results(int *cust_num, int *kwh, double *rate){

printf("\nTotal Customers: %5d, Total kwh: %5d, Total charge: %5.2f",   
*cust_num, *kwh, *rate);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the log / error message / dump information?

Comment: run the code under a debugger (you don't say what platform you are on) this will give more info about where its going wrong

Comment: I am using Dev C++ .

Comment: After working on this and playing around with pointers in function in a side project I came to a workable solution.  Because this is a school assignment, I do not want to put the complete code on here just because I do not want someone who might be in my class to have access to a complete code.

Comment: I would suggest in the future to express how would you like it to behave as well as how it currently behaves.  While we can likely deduce the current behavior from the code, we are unaware of your understanding of some concepts that would be necessary here.  Your misunderstanding of the `scanf` function's requirements as addressed in [Sourav's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28681463/539810) is one example of what I mean.  That said, it was a decent question other than that, and I encourage you to ask more like it if you experience such difficulty in the future.

Comment: Also, as a comment noted, adjust your IDE to turn up the warning level.  It may even tell you that it's the `-Wall` compiler option.  Oh, and if you're using the defunct Bloodshed Dev-C++ IDE instead of the actively developed [Orwell Dev-C++ IDE](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/), I'd recommend switching if possible since Bloodshed's is pretty outdated at best and broken at worst, even on Windows XP.  Test the Orwell IDE before uninstalling the Bloodshed IDE, and if it works for you (and you're allowed to switch), I'd use the Orwell one.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues in your code. To start with,

Point 1. `scanf("%c", ans);` should be `scanf(" %c", &ans);`

Point 2. you're doing `tot_cust ++;`, without initializing `tot_cust`.

Point 3. in `get_data()` function, `cust_num` and `kwh` are pointers. You don't need to put `&` while using in `scanf()`.

Point 4. `*cust_num = *cust_num;` and `*kwh = *kwh;` statements are not required.

and *maybe* many more. As suggested by Mr. **@WhozCraig**, please enable compiler warnings and try to fix them.

Comment: Note: Most of the issues in this code are identifiable if warnings are turned up on the compiler to pedantic levels.

Comment: @WhozCraig Absolutely. Updated my answer to include the suggestion.